# How to save a list as a macro for pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, pgfplots

I want to create and store a list then use that list in a `pgfplots` scatterplot. My attempt is

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\listA}{ (1,2) (2,3) (3,4) (4,5) }

\begin{tikzpicture} \begin{axis}[]
    \addplot+[only marks] 
    coordinates {
     \listA 
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This yields the error "Sorry, I could not read the plot coordinates near ' (1,2) (2,3) (3,4) (4,5) '. Please check for format mistakes. " Replacing `\listA` by its definition works fine, however.

Comment: Have a look at package `pgfplotstable`. You can store values this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually don't know why your document does not compile, but As @Johannes_B said in his comment, you can use the [`pgfplotstable`](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplotstable.pdf) package to create or generate data and reuse it later to plot it with pgfplots or to typeset the actual table. The package offers many options for typesetting and to parse the tabular data. Here is an example that uses your example data.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{
x   y
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   5
}{\tableA}

A Plot:\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot+[only marks] 
            table {\tableA};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

A Table:\quad
\pgfplotstabletypeset{\tableA}
\end{document}
```

[image]